# French Apostrophe is turned into ... when exporting ggplot to PDF

Tags: r, ggplot2

When saving a ggplot as pdf the french apostrophe is turned into ...

While, saving as png behaves as expected preserving the apostrophe.

See images for examples of the output.

[image: Correct export]

[image: Incorrect export]

I am exporting an rmd file to pdf through latex, and the ggplot figures are saved as pdf.

How can I export to pdf and preserve the apostrophe in the titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be certain without seeing your code, but switching to the `cairo_pdf` output device will probably resolve this.

The `rmarkdown` example file below shows PDF output with the `pdf` device (which is the default) and the `cairo_pdf` device. I've used the curly single apostrophe (unicode character `\u2019`), which I think is the character you're trying to render.

In the rmarkdown file, I've set a separate output device in each code chunk. However, you can set the output device once for the entire document by running the following in the first code chunk:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev="cairo_pdf")
```

##### Example rmarkdown document with PDF output

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
```

```{r, fig.height=2, dev="pdf"}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() +
  labs(title = "C\u2019est le titre") +
  theme_bw(base_size=15)
```

```{r, fig.height=2, dev="cairo_pdf"}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) + geom_point() +
  labs(title = "C\u2019est le titre") +
  theme_bw(base_size=15)
```
````

[image]